# How to install scikit-learn for Portable Python?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, portable-python

While I am trying to install scikit-learn for my portable python, its saying " Python 2.7 is not found in the registry". In the next window, it does ask for an installation path but neither am I able to copy-paste the path nor write it manually. Otherwise please suggest some other alternative for portable python which has numpy, scipy and scikit-learn by default. Please note that I don't have administrative rights of the system so a portable version is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my other answer:

Since you are using Portable Python, the best way to install modules is to use easy install. Go to your Portable Python folder directory: `Portable Python 2.7.6.1`.

Next open a command prompt in that location by `Shift + Right Click`.

Then type the following:

```
App\Scripts\easy_install.exe YourModuleNameHere
```

Example to install scikit-learn:

```
App\Scripts\easy_install.exe scikit-learn 

enter code here`enter code here`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily download SciKit executable, extract it with python, copy SciKit folder and content to **c:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\Lib\site-packages\** and you'll have SciKit in your portable python.
I just had this problem and solved this way.

Comment: Extra info: Open the .exe file with a archive extractor (like winrar) and copy the sklearn folder to c:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\Lib\site-packages\ . Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can download the new portable python setup from the http://koen.me/research/teaching-asci/PortablePython.zip . This setup already contains the scikit-learn.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're on Windows, [WinPython](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) is a 64bit portable distribution that contains scikit-learn as an optional component.
Afaik, this is the only 64 bit distribution with the scipy stack for Windows.